# SequentialResult, how does it work in Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

1. Is the **Completed** event fired after the completion of each `IResult` or after the completion of all `IResult`s ?
2. Is the `Execute` method of the `SequentialResult` a blocking method or does it return immediately ?
3. If an `IResult` in the list canceled execution by setting `WasCanceled` on `ResultCompletionEventArgs` to true, what does that mean for the whole sequence, will it cancel the remaining `IResult`s or continue as normal ?
   *Note: Any further explanations, remarks, corrections are welcomed.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. After all children have been executed successfully or after a child throws an exception or is canceled.
2. Implementation detail: It blocks while the first child's `Execute` method runs.
3. See the answer to #1: It cancels the whole sequence.

`SequentialResult` is an implementation of the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Comment: Good catch that it blocks only for first execute. I would have just blurted out that it's non-blocking.

Comment: Actually, I need to make a correction. `Execute` method itself is blocking. If `IResult`s that you passed in are blocking, then `SequentialResult` will also be blocking. Once `SequentialResult` reaches an `IResult` which operates asynchronously, work it forked onto another thread. E.g. you can pass a collection of 3 `ExampleBlockingResult`s and 3 `ExampleNonBlockingResult`s. `SequentialResult` will then be blocked until it finishes blocking results, and first non blocking results. Once first non-blocking result spawns its new worker thread, work is continued from it's `Completed` callbacks.